# Finding primitive roots using Java

Tags: java, primitive, modulus

I am trying to get the first primitive root of a prime number:

```
private static int GetPrime(int factors[], int modul) {

    for (int i = 2; i < modul; i++) {
        int j = 0;
        while (j < factors.length) {
            int power = (modul - 1) / factors[j];
            long g = (long) Math.pow(i, power);
            long mod = g % modul;

            if (mod == 1) {
                j++;
                break;
            } else if (j + 1 == factors.length) {
                return i;
            }
            j++;

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As parameters i have prime factors of number (factors) and prime number (modul). I tried to implement function for finding the first prime root, for some numbers it works, but for other it fails. Forexample it gives the correct answer for 23 which is 5, but for 71 it fails, instead of 7 it gives 3. I can't figure out what is wrong.
Basically formula is n^((modul-1)/factor) % modul, if for one of factors the reminder for each n is 1, then n is not a prime root.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: Please provide sample input for factors and modul.

Comment: factors: 11,2 and modul: 23. Result should be 5